# FactoryGirl first created object used even when specify the second one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, factory-bot

I can't really understand this. I have a course factory that I use to create two objects. When I visit the page for the Accounting course (as seen below) it displays the Marketing course page. However, if I use factory girl to create the accounting course first then it visits the correct page and the test passes.

```
describe "Course pages" do

  subject { page }

  let!(:published_course) { FactoryGirl.create(:course, title: 'Marketing') }
  let!(:unpublished_course) { FactoryGirl.create(:course, title: 'Accounting') }

  describe "displaying the right page" do
    it "should display the accounting course page" do
      visit course_path(unpublished_course)
      expect(page).to have_content('Accounting')
    end
  end
end
```

It obviously visits the page of the object that is created first, but I don't know why or how to fix this.

Thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`course_path` will generate the correct URL (i.e. containing the correct `id` param), but it's up to your controller to find the course for that id and pass it to your view. Instead, your controller/view must be conspiring to display the first course created.